# How do you fully secure (SSL) a magento page

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

We just installed an ssl certificate, and I am able to open the page with

https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/

But it says, that the connection is partially encrypted. And as I see, there are a lot of internal links "only" with http:// instead of https://

How do I set this correct in Magento? Or do I need to do a htaccess file for this?

Comment: @Ben Lessani - Sonassi not a duplicate - reread the question. When you visit the website it says that not all content is secure. The other question and your answer aren't relevant here.

Comment: how did you make out?

Comment: Hi

I need to see, how I can close this question. I found the problem.

Had one "background" images in a css and with the url http:// instead of https://. I changed this to https:// and now it is okay.

Comment: Accept my answer (use the check mark), I pointed it out, you also have a security issue with your SSL.

Comment: I like to accept the answer... where I do it? I not find a check mark or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond setting Magento in the backend to use `SSL` for your Unsecure base, I recommend using a 3rd party tool or website such as [Why no padlock?](https://www.whynopadlock.com/) that can help detect the non `SSL` elements of your website.

In my experience some modules that aren't very well written are hard codded to do `http://`.

Other areas could be `CSS`, a manually inserted link on your site that was written as `http://`.

`CMS` Blocks and Pages can also be responsible and should be looked at to ensure that they aren't offending.

Use the tool I provided to see where the issue is and correct as necessary.

**EDIT:**

In your case, you have hard codded `CSS` that is responsible:

> **Insecure URL: http://mag.outdoorequipped.com/skin/frontend/smartwave/legenda/images/background.png**
>
> **Found in: https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/skin/frontend/smartwave/legenda/css/custom.css**

You also have a security issue with your servers `SSL` setup:

> **Server supports SSLv3, may be vulnerable to POODLE attack. It is suggested to disable the SSLv3 protocol.
> Server certificate**

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to have your complete website in SSL or only the checkout and customer pages..

If you want your complete website in SSL please change your base url in system->configuration->web->Unsecure and ->Secure to https://yourdomain.ext/

If you only want to have your checkout, customer pages in SSL then you only need to change your Secure Base Url and set "Use secure URL" to yes.